# Plants that will thrive under LED grow lights and are also cat-friendly

Tags: indoors, plant-recommendations, raised-beds, safety

I recently bought two [grow lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IVQ96KY) to utilize a [particular indoor growing space](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/62150/garden-space-in-a-basement-with-dirt-space) in my house where everything perfectly fits. The only trouble is that I'm now discovering that  the plethora of things I had imagined growing in this space are toxic to cats.
Most of the ones the internet suggests require low or indirect light and I'm not sure these plant lights are even suitable for such.
I've already bought cat grass seeds as the foundation for this indoor terrarium, but I'm looking for more plants that are suitable for these grow lights and are also suitable for cats ( our boy cats are particularly silly about tasting plants )

We're open to anything and have already settled on perhaps some daisies, some rosemary, and perhaps some snake grass or ZZ plant, but I'm hoping someone on this site has some other solid suggestions - or at the very least can show us the right way to look for such plants.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you've kept them (especially the males) from using that space as a comfy litter box. :)  Another option for you is that instead of growing only cat friendly plants, you could block the space with one or two old window screens, fastened to the ceiling with hinges and secured from the cats by hook and eyes.

Comment: The only time I've had a cat nibble on dried grasses or plants indoors has been when I had an indoor only cat, and we solved that by providing cat grass for her to eat when she needed to. All my other cats in later years had free access to outside, and they never chewed on any indoor plant, but they did used to nibble on long grass outdoors periodically.

Comment: LOL - @Jurp the clay in it's current state is mostly too hard for the kitties to want to use it as a litter box. But as I was preparing this space, I did indeed find evidence that one of them used it as a litter box just a couple of times.

Comment: Oh yes, we were planning on putting cat grass there to fill in some gaps although I read something that suggested not to do that or else the cats will think all of the plants in that space are edible.

Comment: Here's a list from the ASPCA of plants toxic to cats. It's rather poorly formatted, but it can help you decide what to plant: https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/cats-plant-list

Comment: @Jurp that was very useful in picking out our plants. If you would like to post that as the answer, I'll accept it. Maybe also include this link for future people https://www.purewow.com/family/cat-friendly-plants

Comment: I believe daisies are bad for cats.

Comment: You are correct, but this particular gerbera daisy is not toxic to cats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASPCA has an exhaustive [list of plants that are toxic to cats](https://%20aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/cats-plant-list), which should help you in deciding what to plant. As you noted above, this [link](https://purewow.com/family/cat-friendly-plants) of cat-friendly plants should also be helpful. I would hope that the same plant does not appear on both lists :)